# Error getting Bing Map and youtube with Https Endpoint?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

In the starting i deployed asp.net mvc application to azure with http endpoint.at this time bing map and youtube video are working fine in my cloud application.now my application running with Https by adding the SSL certificate.with https end point am getting problems .when i browse the bing map page and video in my application then display popup messages in browsers like

In Internet Explorer,

**Only Secure content is diplayed. do you want show all content.when i click on the show all content then it display map and youtube video.**

If i not click on the show all content.In addition to these two(map & video)some scripts also not running.

In Chrome,

**"This page has insecure content. Load Anyway.when i click on Load Any way it will work with map,Video and Scripts,but green https goes to red https with cross mark.**

How to run the Bing Map ,Youtube and scripts with https endpoints?

Thanks,

PCSSCP.

Answer (score 1):

I got it now.Bing map is working with https.So here are the two ways to add the Bing Ajax control to your page in HTTP or HTTPS:

HTTP:

```
<script src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.3" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

HTTPS:

```
<script src="https://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.3&s=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now on the HTTPS version notice I changed the URL to start with HTTPS, this is what pulls from the secure site over at the good Bing.

for more information check this link,

http://www.interactivewebs.com/blog/index.php/dotnetnuke-modules/bing-ajax-control-over-https-or-http-secure-ssl/

Thanks & Regards,

PCSSCP.